# Combine two DataFrames that duplicate data

Tags: python, pandas

**edited as previous question was not clear enough**

I want to combine two DataFrames with no overlapping data, and just duplicate the data for each record.

```
letters = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

numbers = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

letters = pd.DataFrame(letters)
    0  1  2
0   a  b  c
1   d  e  f


numbers = pd.DataFrame(numbers)
    0  1  2
0   1  2  3
1   4  5  6
```

I want to combine these two DataFrames to look like this.

```
a b c 1 2 3
a b c 4 5 6
d e f 1 2 3
d e f 4 5 6
```

I've tried all of the join types ('inner', 'outer, etc), merges, and concats that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Are they single column DataFrames?

Comment: No, they are multi-column

Comment: So what happens to the other columns? From which DataFrame do they take the values?

Comment: i wanted them to duplicate as well.  I will edit the question - it was not clear enough.

Comment: You may want to checkout [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get good responses.

Comment: ayhan - thanks for pointing out this cartesian product example (I did not know what to search for).  I will take a look.